# Navigation from Mysite to Main site

Tags: navigation

I have a main sharepoint site configured with some Navigation menu items. I have also have a MYSite. The same Navigation menu items are shared between both the main site and my site. But the navigation from mysite to Main is not working. Please let me know how do I give the links from my site to mainsite.

Comment: If they have the same navigation, how is the link not working? Are you getting an error? Sending to the wrong page? What happens?

Comment: Top the top menu is configured to display as same but not the links to those pages.This means it uses the same master page.

Comment: So when a user clicks on the link back to the main site, what happens?

Comment: It is taking the relative path of the mysite and appending the string of the actual relative path of the main site.

Answer (score 0):

If the home link is part of the master page, can you change the link to be a full url instead of a relative url? If not, you can use some Javascript to update the link to include the full site url instead of a relative url.

Comment: Thanks David. I will do this. Many thanks for your help.